# Is there something like DynDNS for a DNS service?

Tags: firewalls, dns, ip

I run a small DNS server (pihole) at home behind a firewall, with some custom filtering. It mainly filters ads and trackers, plus some top level domains I want to avoid navigating to. I have an IPv4 address (not fixed) with my ISP and could use DynDNS for HTTP traffic to my home.

**Now I would like to use my home-based DNS server on my mobile phone when traveling.** How could I possibly do that?

Since the IP is not fixed, I will not be able to provide a fixed IP for DNS resolution. I would need something that gets the IP first. Like DynDNS for DNS.

**Does such a dynamic IP resolution for DNS exists?**

*Note: I would like to not use a VPN connection since I do not need to re-route the subsequent traffic to my home, I just want to use my DNS server.*

*Note2: I already use noscript and the like in the browser, but I want to get rid of unwanted connections (ads, trackers) in apps too.*

Comment: This seems like a parade example of [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the reason why you would like to use your own DNS server? What problem does it actually solve for you?

Comment: What does a portable DNS server give you?

Comment: This might be better suited for one of the other SE sites. I don't see a connection to information security.

Comment: @MechMK1 It mainly filters ads and trackers, plus some top level domains I want to avoid navigating to.

Comment: @MarcSchütz I can see your point, would you migrate it?

Comment: @Marcel All those things can be solved with things aside from a DNS server. Those solutions may be worth investigating

Comment: @schroeder The DNS server need not be mobile, but I want to remove the burden from loading all that crap on my mobile devices, when not at home, too.

Comment: @MechMK1 It's also about apps, how would you keep those clean? Please see Note2.

Answer (score 1):

You have a [chicken-and-egg problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) here. To dynamically resolve the IP for your DNS resolver, you need a DNS resolver. Such DNS resolver chaining doesn't exist.

Unless you're going to patch the firmware of your mobile phone for some kind of DNS bootstrapping, you may want to set up a resolver somewhere else, like, on a dedicated cloud instance with fixed IPv4/IPv6 address. AWS, DigitalOcean or the likes provide those for a negligible cost.

To tie that somehow to the information security which is the topic of this SE site: to secure the communication between your phone and your DNS server you should use [DNS-over-TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_TLS) (DoT) or [DNS-over-HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS) (DoH), because most of the cellular and Wi-Fi networks would attempt to track what sites you visit. [Here's how](https://facebookexperimental.github.io/doh-proxy/tutorials/nginx-dohhttpproxy-unbound-centos7.html) you can set up a DoH server under CentOS 7 in less than 10 minutes.

Another approach would be to set up a VPN server at home, with your DNS server of choice, and connect to the Web services through that VPN. This way you will get your DNS chaining, as well as probably more secure (or, at least, predictable) browsing experience. However, you would need to learn about how to set up an OpenVPN (or IPSec, or whatever you prefer) server, which might take time.